# How can I hide the price's inside the Cart for unregisterd users wordpress

Tags: wordpress, settings

Basically I have downloaded a plugin to hide price's for unregistered user's. The problem is if the customer clicks on "Add to Cart" button and they go at the Cart they can see the price. Is there any setting to disable prices on cart for unregisterd users or anything related to that?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple way to do this is overwrite cart template and check if user is login then display. I show you the logic. I hope you know how to overwrite template. still brief I say you here. 
This is to overwrite cart.

```
woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php to   
yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php
```

this is for check logic

```
<?php if(is_user_logged_in()){ ?>
     <td class="product-price" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
     <?php
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
     ?>
     </td>
<?php } ?>
```

you also need to do same for label.